# How to get the MSB into a logic gate which will check if a number is negative or not?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, hdl, binary, alu

I need to create a logic gate which will find out whether a number is negative or not.

The input is 8 bits and the output is 1 bit, and if the input is 1 (i.e. negative number) then the output should also be 1, but if the input is 0, then the output should also be 0, so it kinda works like a NOT gate without the inverter.

I've read about the MSB and how it works and that I'd need to feed it in to the input but I'm not entirely sure how to write it. I'm going to be testing this on a HDL, so I'll need to write it a bit like:

```
Not(in=in[1], out=out[1];
```

and so on.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "testing this on a HDL"? Especially clarify whether you mean VHDL or Verilog, but also how exactly you plan to test it; in a simulator? On an actual FPGA? What simulator or FPGA?

Comment: @Felthry i'm writing the actual chip in Visual Studio code. saving it as a .HDL file and then running it in a Hardware Simulator. I'm not exactly sure on the name/version as it's literally called Hardware Simulator

Comment: Visual studio does HDL now? What device are you targeting when you compile it?

Comment: @Felthry [This](https://youtu.be/Yo0trkA-fh4?t=157) is what i'm using. Turns out it's actually called Hardware Simulator 2.5, and the stuff on the left on the video is how my code for it looks like in VS Code.

Comment: In Verilog you'd just `assign signbit = in[7]` and be done. If you have no other option you could cascade two inverters.

Comment: @ThePhoton what do you mean by cascade two inverters? The language that i'm using only allows me to specify the chip name, the inputs and the outputs and nothing else. I've tried doing Not(in=in[7], out=neg); but it doesn't seem to work :/

Comment: Make a new signal like "sign1". Now you can `Not(in=in[7], out=sign1); Not(in=sign1, out=neg)`.

Comment: But there is probably a gate available that does this already. Maybe `Buf` or `Buffer` or something. You are not using a very widely used HDL, so very few people will know the syntax. Maybe only people who've taken the same class you're taking.

Comment: @ThePhoton Thank you, adding the sign1 thing works. Would you be able to tell me how this works, as i'm not entirely sure?

Comment: You invert a signal twice, you get the signal back. Not(Not(A)) == A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Verilog you'd just `assign out = in[7]` and be done.

There might be a gate available in your HDL that does this in one step. It might be named something like `Buf` or `Buffer`.

But if you don't have the documentation for your HDL, or there really is no way to simply tell it that one signal is an alias of another, you  could cascade two inverters.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUdY3J.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As an aside, the language you're using looks more like a netlist language than a full featured HDL. It's probably been designed solely to support your class, and isn't used in industry at all. Your professor or TA is probably the best one to explain the syntax and available gates to you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't do anything. You can use the signal as is:

`if (number[7])
   // do whatever you want when it's negative
else
   // do the positive thing`

Or use an assign statement like suggested in comments.

Comment: So I've written it as Not(in=in[7], out=neg); but it doesn't seem to work. The language that i'm writing it in doesn't allow me to use if statements or whatever, all I can do is specify the chip name, the inputs and the outputs and that's it.

Comment: What's the language? That's not vhdl or verilog, which are the only two mainstream hdls. I used some other fringe researchy ones in school though...

Comment: I honestly don't know, it's one that I use at school so it's probably the "fringe research ones" that you mentioned. It's layed out like the stuff on [here](https://github.com/seebees/nand2tetris/blob/master/projects/01/And.hdl)

Comment: Interesting. It looks like a custom hdl designed for teaching purposes. The only built in is NAND, and you use it to construct every other piece you need. You could certainly build a non-inverting buffer out of two cascaded buffers. But there also might be a way to use the wire directly since you don't need a buffer logically, they're generally used for physical design reasons, and you're modeling logic only. But unless you find people here with experience with this language you probably won't get a useful answer. Ask the instructor!